# Changes to loaded files are not executed

Tags: ruby

I'm debugging a program, and it's not executing the new `puts` in the loaded files. The main file is running, and changes on that file are executed. So I'm skeptical any changes are loaded.

What could I be doing wrong?

The first file works fine. its the second file... the newmods.rb file that the prompt isn't changing when run, and any new 'puts' statements are not taking. 
I'm using load instead of require_relative. the file doesn't compile with require_relative.

File 1

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby 
load "/Users/abcde/Ruby/learning/shorterZork/monsters.rb"
load "/Users/abcde/Ruby/learning/shorterZork/room.rb"
load "/Users/abcde/Ruby/learning/shorterZork/avatar.rb"
load "/Users/abcde/Ruby/learning/shorterZork/newmods.rb"
load "/Users/abcde/Ruby/learning/shorterZork/items.rb"

def main()

  game_loop(avatar)

end

def game_loop(avatar)

 puts "You are in the: #{@room_name}"
 puts "#{avatar.name} has #{avatar.life}!"      
 health_bar(avatar)
 # Check for avatar's life. 
 #avatar_life(avatar) 
 #puts @room_monsters.to_s
 monster = @room_monsters
 test_encounter(avatar, monster)
 # need to put the meat of the game here. 
 # puts "I need something here."
 #puts "--------------------------------------------This is the main loop."

 prompt; action = gets.chomp

  if action.downcase == "help"
   help() 

 ..etc...etc.

end

main()
```

File 2 newmods.rb

```
# This includes any modules that might be nice to use. 

load "/Users/abcde/Ruby/learning/shorterZork/monsters.rb"
load "/Users/abcde/Ruby/learning/shorterZork/room.rb"
load "/Users/abcde/Ruby/learning/shorterZork/avatar.rb"
load "/Users/abcde/Ruby/learning/shorterZork/items.rb"

#require 'items'
#require 'monsters'
#require 'avatar'
#require 'room'
#require 'shortZork'

def prompt()
  print ">> "
end
```

Comment: Could you post some code, and an example of how you're running the program?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Joy. Just when you reach out for help the answer slaps you in the face.

The ruby load is loading a file from a different path than the current expected path. The username is different, so...

Answer (score 0):

From my experience, common mistakes in such cases are

- The edit displayed on the editor/IDE is not saved to the file.
- There are different versions of a file, and the edit is made on the version that is not used.